# How to create a blinking line in android?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

I am using a line by using canvas in android as shown below.

```
canvas.drawLine(100,100,600, 600,mpaint);
```

I want this line to blink continuously. If anyone know about this, please help me...

Comment: I don't know the answer. But, i've one suggestion for you. [Try like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9294196/940096)

Comment: I'm not sure about this, refer this link, here they worked with textview, if it possible means you can modify it http://android-vogue.blogspot.in/2011/05/how-to-blink-text-view-in-every-1.html

Comment: Please give more details about the context. Where do you get your canvas from ?

Comment: Hi @Spk, Thanks for your reply.. I know about that u suggested.. I think its only for TextViews,Buttons etc.. Here I wants it for canvas... Could u please Help me, if you know about it...

Comment: Oh Okay. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9947185/940096)

Comment: Thanks to all for ur replies....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the line appear to blink you'll have to alternate between to different colors:

- `Draw red line`
- `Draw blue line`

You can simply do this with the following:

```
boolean blink = false;

// Define paint objects
Paint red = new Paint;
red.setColor(Color.RED);
Paint blue = new Paint;
blue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
```

In your update method you do this:

```
if(blink == false) {
blink = true;

}
else {
blink = false;
}
```

In your rendering method:

```
if(blink == true) {
canvas.drawLine(100,100,600, 600,red);
}
else {
canvas.drawLine(100,100,600, 600,blue);
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: `if (blink == false) blink = true...` You haven't considered `blink = !blink;`? canvas.drawLine can also be simplified to `canvas.drawLine(100,100,600, 600, blink ? red : blue);`